# How can the Three-Phase Commit Protocol (3PC) guarantee atomicity?

Tags: transactions, commit

I'm currently exploring worst case scenarios of atomic commit protocols like 2PC and 3PC and am stuck at the point that I can't find out **why 3PC can guarantee atomicity**. That is, how does it guarantee that if cohort A commits, cohort B also commits?

Here's the simplified [3PC from the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3PC):

[image: 3PC commit protocol as depicted on English Wikipedia]

Now let's assume the following case:

1. Two cohorts participate in the transaction (A and B)
2. Both do their work, then vote for commit
3. Coordinator now sends precommit messages...

   - A receives the precommit message, acknowledges, and then goes offline for a long time
   - B doesn't receive the precommit message (whatever the reason might be) and is thus still in "uncertain" state

The results:

- **Coordinator aborts** the transaction because not all precommit messages were sent and acknowledged successfully
- **A**, who is in precommit state, is still offline, thus times out and **commits**
- **B aborts** in any case: He either stays offline and times out (causes abort) or comes online and receives the abort command from the coordinator

And there you have it: One cohort committed, another aborted. **The transaction is screwed.**

So what am I missing here? In my understanding, if the automatic commit on timeout (in precommit state) was replaced by infinitely waiting for a coordinator command, that case should work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The article you quoted seems to cover this eventuality quite accurately: "The main disadvantage to this algorithm is that it cannot recover in the event the network is segmented in any manner." The case you've noted, where "A" simply goes off-line, translates to the "the network has been segmented" -- i.e. "A" is now in one segment, while "B" and the "Coordinator" are in another segment.

Various enhanced 3PC protocols to deal with this problem are discussed (among other places) in a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c7c6/e4a790582b776eca168f60ca27d4bd8d2a3a.pdf) by Kempster, Stirling and Thannish.

Comment: Okay, that confirms my thesis. I will read up on these quorum-based protocols. Thank you